# How do I optimize my code to sum numbers up to infinity or very large numbers in the specific formula below?

Tags: python, math, formula, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to code a formula in python to determine the Bernoulli trials with success probability p. The formula is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLelO.jpg

The code below works fine for small numbers like if input were `outerSum(2,20,7,.25,.75)` it would evaluate to around 2.44 x 10^-6 (which is correct, I checked with maple).

However my problem is when I run it on large numbers(which I am using the formula for) the code does not work for it and gives me an error: `ValueError: -inf + inf in fsum`.

My ideal input would be `outerSum(2,31290,1755,.25,.75)` however I am receiving the error from above. How do I optimize my code to sum numbers up to infinity or very large numbers in the specific formula below? An ideal input scenario would be `outerSum(2,31290,1755,.25,.75)`

```
import math
from sympy import binomial
import numpy
def innerSum(k,n,x,y):
   #z = ((n - k * x - y) / k)

   f = []
   g = 0
   for j in range(0, int(math.floor(n - k * x - y / k))):
     b = math.pow(-1, j)
     c = binomial(y + 1, j)
     d = binomial(n - k * x - j * k, y)

     e = b * c * d
     f.append(e)
     g = math.fsum(f)

  return g

def outerSum(k,n,x,p,q):
  a = math.floor((n - k * x) / k)  # math.floor(((n-k*x)/k))
  a = int(a)
  b = (n - k * x)
  b = int(b)

  h = []

  for y in range(a, b + 1):
    c = math.pow(q, y)
    d = math.pow(p, n - y)
    e = binomial(y + x, x)

    f = innerSum(k, n, x, y)

    g = c*d*e*f
    h.append(g)
    i = math.fsum(h)
    #print(i)
  print(i)

outerSum(2,20,7,.25,.75)
```

Comment: I have tried editing my code for a few hours but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: what is binomial? Are you missing an import?

Comment: I have the correct imports and they are: import math
from sympy import binomial
import numpy

Comment: They are not in the question. Also there are some indentation errors. Could you edit and correct the question?

Comment: I just did that

Comment: Its the binomial that's giving the `inf`, may be you could try and normalize/scale the result of the binomial and later multiply it.